# Trying to get list of records but getting null

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, null

ActionMethod:

```
    [HttpGet("facilitytypes")]
    public async Task<List<FacilityType>> GetFacilityTypes()
    {          
        return  await _context.FacilityType.ToListAsync();
    }
```

FacilityType model:

```
    public int FacilityTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public ulong? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? CatalogId { get; set; }
```

I am using mysql for Database despite having records in the following table I am getting null while other tables are working fine.

Comment: By "getting null" do you mean getting *empty list*? Also I see `IsDeleted` property, which implies soft delete and global query filter, are you sure your table records are not just filtered out?

Comment: By getting null mean I get count =0 every time even though I have data in database.

Comment: Ok, then how about global query filters? Do you get records if you issue `await _context.FacilityType.IgnoreQueryFilters().ToListAsync()`?

Comment: Ivan Steov thanks for reminding about global query filter I use IgnoreQueryFilters() now its working fine.

Comment: Yes I get the data using await _context.FacilityType.IgnoreQueryFilters().ToListAsync() now its working.